# Site-recommendation: Question about home office setup

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a PC, Macbook and HP Laptop, and I want to have a good home-office setup with KVM shared through USBC (HP), Thunderbolt (Macbook), USB 2.0 (PC).

Which community do I ask this to?

Comment: If you can identify specific issues that you have questions about, you might be able to ask on [su]. If you just want to know "How do I set this up" or "What's the best blahblah to use", there isn't really any site on the SE network that such questions are appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

- https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com if you want to choose which hardware to purchase.
- https://superuser.com/ if you already have hardware but have questions on how it works.